# Distance problem - aptitude

Tags: linear-algebra

Tim and Elan are 90 km from each other.they start to move each other simultanously tim at speed 10 and elan 5 kmph. If every hour they double their speed what is the distance that Tim will pass until he meet Elan.

If we draw it on a scale, Tim goes 10, 30, 70...while Elan goes 85, 75, 55...

Options are 60, 30, 80 and 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubling each speed is the same as doubling the relative velocity. The relative velocity starts at $15$, so the next hour it will be $30$, and the next $60$.

Since we want $90$ to be traveled between the both of them, we know it's after $2$ hours ($45 km$) and before $3$ ($105$ km). So after $2$ hours, they have $45$ km left to go, traveling at $60$ km/hr. So they meet at $2$ hours, $45$ minutes.

So if we want to find the distance traveled by Tim, we have his first speed*$1$ hr plus his second speed*$1$ hr plus the his third speed times $.75$ of an hour. So $10+20+40(.75)=60$ km.

Comment: Wow! Got it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! But for future reference, I wouldn't use the linear algebra tag for an algebraic word problem. Linear algebra is the study of vector spaces and linear mappings.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

So, on cumulative effort, they travel together $$5+10=15,2(5+10)=30,2\cdot30$$

So, after two hours they travel $15+30=45$ KM leaving $90-45=45$KM to be covered at a total speed $=60$KM/hour

Answer (score 0):

If every hour each one double their speed then tim goes 10, 20, 40 ... While len goes 5, 10, 15. Considering they are moving to each other we can sim their speeds and sais they are closing each at speed of 15, 30, 60... Etc.Now we need the sum of distances in order to surpass 100 kilometers, we use sum of all the 15*2^(n-1) where n begins in one which is the first hour and continue until the sum become bigger than 100 The answer is 3 since 15+30+60=105 this means by three hours they already found each other. So by a time bigger than 2 hours and minor to three they find, take in mind that after two hours they are closing at they speed of 60 kilometers and by two hours they already have closed 45  kilometers (sum from n=1 to n=2), so they have 55 kilometers ahead at the speed of 60 km/h which is the same of 1km per minute, so those complety the 55 km in 55 minutes.
Im conclusion they need 2 hours and 55 minutes to find each other.